# Firefox addons: How to set default preferences depending on platform?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am creating an addon for Mozilla Firefox, and one of the preferences is a filepath in the file system (specifically, the executable file or the command for VLC player). That filepath is changeable through the preference window, but an addition of a default value for that preference would be helpful.

Since the addon is supposed to work on both Linux and Windows operating systems, my wish is to include default filepaths for each operating system, so it would look something like this:

Linux: `/usr/bin/vlc`

Windows x86 `C:\\Program Files\\VideoLan\\VLC\\vlc.exe`

Windows x86_64 `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLan\\VLC\\vlc.exe` 
(since the default VLC installation will always be 32-bit)

Is there a way to achieve this? So far I can only put one `defaults.js` file describing the preference (for example for Linux):

`pref("extensions.vlc_shortcut.vlc_filepath", "/usr/bin/vlc");`

That file is located in `my_extension/defaults/preferences/defaults.js`, I have tried putting if-else statements in the file, but to no effect. I even tried putting the following if statement:

```
if(true)
    pref("extensions.vlc_shortcut.vlc_filepath", "/usr/bin/vlc");
```

but it ignores everything, as if it is a blank file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't set platform-specific values in the default preferences. According to the [MDN article on default preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Default_Preferences):

> The actual file, despite having .js extension, is not a JavaScript file. You may not set variables inside of it, nor may do any kind of program flow control (ifs, loops etc.) nor even calculated values (i.e. 3600 * 24 * 5). Doing so will cause Mozilla to stop processing your preferences file without any notification, warning, error, or exception. Think of it more as an .ini file. Comments are perfectly acceptable.

Another approach is to use [nsIXULRuntime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIXULRuntime) to determine the host OS and path accordingly.

Here's the example from MDN:

```
var xulRuntime = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xre/app-info;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIXULRuntime);

alert(xulRuntime.OS);
```

If desired, you can save the path as a preference using the [Preferences API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Preferences_API).

Another option to consider is bundling (if the license allows), in which case you can indicate [platform-specific files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Bundles#Platform-specific_files) in the manifest.

Comment: Avoid `.getService` if possible by using [Services.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm): `Services.appinfo.OS`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @nmaier! Can you say a bit about why it's better to use Services.jsm?

Comment: For one, Services.jsm getters are cached (memoized), so you avoid the overhead of `.getService()` and the overhead of having the javascript XPConnect wrappers garbage collected later on. That overhead would probably be negligible in this case, seeing it is a single call only. There are cases where it does matter, though. The killer argument for me as somebody who performed a couple of thousand add-on code reviews is readability.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. I went to research a bit into components and modules, and right now I'm trying them out as a workaround for setting the default preferences. And I'll use Services.jsm.

Comment: Regarding the comment, "No, you can't set platform-specific values in the default preferences.", technically, you can, although it may be frowned upon by some as unorthodox, unclean, or inefficient, etc.  Consider, for the sake of argument, options `.vlc_filepath_linux`, `.vlc_filepath_winx86`, `.vlc_filepath_winx64`.  The platform-specific default names could match the output of `xulRuntime.OS`, but that may not help you determine if you're on x86 or x64, as it simply outputs `WINNT`.  In any case, regardless where you store the default paths, you must detect and select in JS code elsewhere.